# How can a 21 byte UTF-8 sequence come from just 5 characters?

Tags: java, unicode, encoding, utf-8, string-length

After writing some basic code to count the number of characters in a `String`, I've found one example where the UTF-8 encoded output creates 21 bytes from a 5 "character" `String`.

Here's the output:

> ```
> String ==¦ อภิชาติ ¦==
> Code units 7
> UTF8 Bytes 21
> 8859 Bytes 7
> Characters 5
> ```

I understand that Java's internal representation of a `char` is 2 bytes and there is a possibility that some characters may require two Unicode code units to display them.

As UTF-8 doesn't use any more than 4 bytes per character, how is a `byte[]` length of more than 20 possible for a 5 character `String`?

Here's the source:

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

public class StringTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        displayStringInfo("อภิชาติ");
    }

    public static void displayStringInfo(String s) {
        System.out.println("Code units " + s.length());     
        try {
            System.out.println("UTF8 Bytes " + s.getBytes("UTF-8").length);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) { // not handled }
        System.out.println("Characters " + characterLength(s));
    }

    public static int characterLength(String s) {
        int count = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++) {
            if(!isLeadingUnit(s.charAt(i)) && !isMark(s.charAt(i))) count++;
        }
        return count;
    }

    private static boolean isMark(char ch) {
        int type = Character.getType(ch);
        return (type == Character.NON_SPACING_MARK ||
               type == Character.ENCLOSING_MARK ||
               type == Character.COMBINING_SPACING_MARK);
    }

    private static boolean isLeadingUnit(char ch) {
        return Character.isHighSurrogate(ch);
    }
}
```

Comment: when i edit this `อภิชาติ` in notepad, `ภิ` seems like 2 characters (same goes for `ติ`)

Comment: Yes, I had assumed they were all composed characters but two of them seem to combine a diacritical mark "character".

Comment: It's time to stop using the word 'character'. it's codepoint, glyph or what. utf8everywhere.org

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your "5 character" string actually consists of 7 Unicode code points:

- U+0E2D THAI CHARACTER O ANG
- U+0E20 THAI CHARACTER PHO SAMPHAO
- U+0E34 THAI CHARACTER SARA I
- U+0E0A THAI CHARACTER CHO CHANG
- U+0E32 THAI CHARACTER SARA AA
- U+0E15 THAI CHARACTER TO TAO
- U+0E34 THAI CHARACTER SARA I

All of them are in the U+0800 to U+FFFF range that requires 3 bytes per character in UTF-8, hence a total length of 7×3 = 21 bytes.

Comment: Thanks, for a moment I stupidly forgot that UTF-8 can use more bytes than UTF-16 in the upper range. As my results showed me that I had 7 Unicode code points, this should have been obvious.

Answer (score 3):

There're **7** characters in the string:

```
 ' อ' (0x0e2d) encoded as {0xe0, 0xb8, 0xad}
  'ภ' (0x0e20) - / -      {0xe0, 0xb8, 0xa0}
  ' ิ' (0x0e34) - / -      {0xe0, 0xb8, 0xb4}
  'ช' (0x0e0a) - / -      {0xe0, 0xb8, 0x8a}
  'า' (0x0e32) - / -      {0xe0, 0xb8, 0xb2}
  'ต' (0x0e15) - / -      {0xe0, 0xb8, 0x95}
  ' ิ' (0x0e34) - / -      {0xe0, 0xb8, 0xb4}
```

each symbol is encoded by *three bytes* in UTF-8 and so 
you have `7 * 3 == 21` bytes altogeter